# docker gitlab-ci ssh php-web, get read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

Tags: php, git, docker, ssh, gitlab

ssh debug show that

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /dev/fd/63 RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
lost connection
```

gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - deploy
before_script:
  - echo "ssh-user:$SSH_USER"
  - echo "ssh-host:$SSH_HOST"
  - echo "ci-pro-dir:$CI_PROJECT_DIR"
  - export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\\n\\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\\n\\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
variables:
  SERVER_PATH: "/home/xxx/www/xxxx"
docker-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - scp -v -r $CI_PROJECT_DIR $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST:$SERVER_PATH
  tags:
    - xxx-xxx
  only:
    - master
```

use ssh to scp file-folder, but show read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

there are "/dev/tty" exists

no idea to solve, should i delete "/dev/tty" and rebuild it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try to simply ssh to the host from shell?
In this case we would see if SSH is possible without debugging gitlab-ci

Comment: i have found the answer, `/root is 744, should be 700`, thank you for your answer, so kind of you.

Answer (score 1):

@George Goglodze

has tried it, also not work. the pub key had put to authorized_keys,the private key had send to ssh-agent by used varible

```
$ scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -v -r $CI_PROJECT_DIR $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST:$SERVER_PATH
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host xxx.xx.xxx.xxx, user root, command scp -v -r -t /home/dnmp/www/icitysecret_backend
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Warning: Permanently added 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: root@xxxxxxxxxxxxxx RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0)


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0)


debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: root@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
root@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
lost connection
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try the next:
1.Generate public/private rsa key pair first.
2.Copy public key as authorized_key:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Comment: i did that / `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` / `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` / but not work

Comment: Can you try to use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` during scp?     

`scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -v -r $CI_PROJECT_DIR $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST:$SERVER_PATH`

also, make sure ~/.ssh/authorized_keys the file is present at $SSH_HOST

Comment: answer in up floortr